# How to animate a Drawable in a custom view?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-custom-view, android-drawable

I currently have a custom view with a Drawable resource that I want to animate moving it from one position to another. I know there are two ways to implement `PropertyAnimation`, you can do it by using `ValueAnimation` or `ObjectAnimation`. But with both I didn't find any information on Google docs about how to use them with a Drawable instead of a View. [This](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-custom-view-tutorial-part-4-animation/) is the only example I found that is similar to my problem, and so I've tryed to implement it in my code:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button animate;
    private CustomView mView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mView = new CustomView(MainActivity.this);

        animate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.animate);
        animate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mView.startAnimation();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**CustomView**

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private Drawable drawable;
    private Rect drawableRect;
    private int newPos;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.my_drawable);
        drawableRect= new Rect();
        newPos = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        drawableRect.left = 0;
        drawableRect.top = newPos;
        drawableRect.right = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        drawableRect.bottom = newPos + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        drawable.setBounds(drawableRect);
        drawable.draw(canvas);

    }

    public void startAnimation() {

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 200);
        animator.setDuration(1500);

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                newPos = ((Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue()).intValue();
                CustomView.this.invalidate();
            }
        });

        animator.start();
        invalidate();

    }

}
```

But with no effect. The value of `newPos` changes properly (checked with Logs) and the screen gets updated (checked with surface update) but the Drawable does not move. What am I doing wrong? Hoping in any help.

Comment: Did you check that `newPos` change for something different of 0 ? Add some logs or break points and try again if you haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[周恩旭](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5168673/%E5%91%A8%E6%81%A9%E6%97%AD) eventually took me to the solution. I was doing a stupid error in `MainActivity` because I was creating a new reference to the `CustomView`:

```
mView = new CustomView(MainActivity.this);
```

and trying to animate using that object reference. Solved this by replacing it with:

```
mView = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.custom_view);
```

Answer (score 3):

I try to run your code that the `CustomView`, it's efficient, it's have animation.

Are you sure you execute the method `startAnimation`?

I add the `startAnimation()` to the construction `NoteCustomView`, I can see the animation when UI finish load.

Code at below, I use the ic_launcher as drawable. And I add the NoteCustomView to activity's layout xml.

```
public class NoteCustomView extends View {

    private Drawable drawable;
    private Rect drawableRect;
    private int newPos;

    public NoteCustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);

    }

    public NoteCustomView(final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        drawableRect= new Rect();
        newPos = 0;
        startAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        drawableRect.left = 0;
        drawableRect.top = newPos;
        drawableRect.right = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        drawableRect.bottom = newPos + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        drawable.setBounds(drawableRect);
        drawable.draw(canvas);

    }

    public void startAnimation() {

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 200);
        animator.setDuration(1500);

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                newPos = ((Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue()).intValue();
                NoteCustomView.this.invalidate();
            }
        });

        animator.start();
        invalidate();

    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, so in this way the animation works, but if I call `startAnimation()` from the Activity it does not work. Take a look at my updated code.

Comment: In my way, I use the xml, it's efficient. Maybe you didn't add `addView(mView)` in the Activity's `onCreate()`?

Comment: Why should I add `addView(mView)` in `onCreate()`? The view is already drawn with `setContentView()` method. I only need a reference to the custom view, because I want to start the animation from the activity, but this seems not to work.

Comment: bcz you use the `new CustomView(this)`, it's not inside the layout, you should use `addView` to make the layout load CustomView. You also can try my way, In my code, has two construction, add CustomView to activity_main.xml